# Sql: Select count(*) from (select ...)

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, subquery

I have a sql select command with grouping and I want to get the number of total rows. How do I achieve that?

My sql command:

```
select p.UserName, p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName as [FullName]
 ,count(b.billid) as [Count], sum(b.PercentRials) as [Sum] from Bills b
inner join UserProfiles p on b.PayerUserName=p.UserName
 where b.Successful=1
 group by p.UserName, p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName
```

I have tried these with no luck:

```
select count(*) from (select ...)
```

and

```
select count(select ...)
```

**EDIT**

this is the complete sql statement that I want to run:

```
select count(*) from (    select p.UserName, p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName as [FullName]
 ,count(b.billid) as [Count], sum(b.PercentRials) as [Sum] from Bills b
inner join UserProfiles p on b.PayerUserName=p.UserName
 where b.Successful=1
 group by p.UserName, p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName)
```

and I get this error on the last line:

```
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: for `select count(*) from (select ...)`: `Incorrect syntax near ')'.`

Comment: @Mahmoodvcs, can you post complete code for that SELECT statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM 
(
select p.UserName, p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName as [FullName]
 ,count(b.billid) as [Count], sum(b.PercentRials) as [Sum] from Bills b
inner join UserProfiles p on b.PayerUserName=p.UserName
 where b.Successful=1
 group by p.UserName, p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName   --<-- Removed the extra comma here
) A  --<-- Use an Alias here
```

As I expected from your shown attempt you were missing an Alias

```
select count(*) 
from (select ...) Q  --<-- This sub-query in From clause needs an Alias
```

**Edit**

If you only need to know the rows returned by this query and you are executing this query anyway somwhere in your code you could simply make use of [`@@ROWCOUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187316.aspx) function. Something like....

```
SELECT ......     --<-- Your Query

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT    --<-- This will return the number of rows returned 
                       -- by the previous query
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (
           SELECT p.UserName
               ,p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName AS [FullName]
               ,COUNT(b.billid) AS [Count]
               ,SUM(b.PercentRials) AS [Sum]
            FROM Bills b
            INNER JOIN UserProfiles p
                ON b.PayerUserName = p.UserName
            WHERE b.Successful = 1
            GROUP BY p.UserName
               ,p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName
         ) a
```

based on your edit. You were missing derived tabled alias.

If you look at `FROM` clause syntax you will see

> | **derived_table [ AS ] table_alias** [ ( column_alias [ ,...n ] ) ]
>
> When a derived table, rowset or table-valued function, or operator
>   clause (such as PIVOT or UNPIVOT) is used, the **required table_alias** at
>   the end of the clause is the associated table name for all columns,
>   including grouping columns, returned.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx

Comment: WOW! Thanks a lot. I didn't know about the alias.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an alias after your subquery

```
select count(*) from (select ...) v
```

You can also try to return total count using existing SQL, without using subquery

```
select p.UserName, 
p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName as [FullName],
count(b.billid) as [Count], 
sum(b.PercentRials) as [Sum],
COUNT(*) over () [TotalCount] ------- total count here
from Bills b
inner join UserProfiles p on b.PayerUserName=p.UserName
where b.Successful=1
group by p.UserName, p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName
```

Comment: I've found about `count(*) over()` while I was searching, but in my situation I needed another select for just the count. Thanks a lot anyway. Great answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a unique column name in there, you can count that.  For example I'm assuming UserName is unique here.

```
select count(query.UserName) from ( 
select p.UserName, p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName as [FullName]
 ,count(b.billid) as [Count], sum(b.PercentRials) as [Sum] from Bills b
inner join UserProfiles p on b.PayerUserName=p.UserName
 where b.Successful=1
 group by p.UserName, p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName) as query
```

Answer (score -2):

COUNT() - aggregate function

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM ...;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS(); // next query !!!!